# Prove that this function is continuous at $(0,0)$

Tags: limits, continuity

I need to prove that the function is continuous at $(0,0)$.

$$f(x,y)=\frac{2x^2y^2}{x^2+y^2}, \text{ if } (x,y)\neq(0,0)$$
and $0 \text{ if } (x,y)=(0,0)$

---

I'm trying to prove that $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{2x^2y^2}{x^2+y^2}=0$$

but I don't know how to relate it to $$0\leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\leq  \delta.$$ Finally I have $$2(x^2+y^2)\leq \epsilon.$$ Any ideas that can help me?

Answer (score 5):

Note that for any $\epsilon>0$ we have (using the AM-GM inequality)

$$\begin{align}
0<\left|\frac{2x^2y^2}{x^2+y^2}\right|&\le \left|\frac{2x^2y^2}{2|x||y|}\right|\\\\
&=|x||y|\\\\
&\le \frac12(x^2+y^2)\\\\
&<\epsilon
\end{align}$$

whenever $0<\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta=\sqrt{2\epsilon}$

Comment: (+1) That's nicer than my answer.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you!  Much appreciated my friend.

Answer (score 4):

You have

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{2x^2y^2}{x^2+y^2} & = \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{2}{\frac{1}{y^2}+\frac{1}{x^2}} \\
& = 0
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

This is because the numerator is fixed at $2$ but the denominator goes to infinity as $x$ and $y$ go to $0$.

Alternatively, you could also use the [squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) by using

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
0 \le \frac{2x^2y^2}{x^2+y^2} \le \frac{2x^2y^2}{y^2} = 2x^2
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Comment: really very interesting, but we still don't see the theorem and we are only using the definition.

Comment: @YobaniOrdoñez If by "definition" you mean using an $\epsilon-\delta$ proof as you tried in your question, note that [José Carlos Santos](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/446262/jos%c3%a9-carlos-santos)'s [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3592326/602049) shows the way I would have also basically done it.

Answer (score 4):

Since $x^2,y^2\leqslant x^2+y^2$,$$0\leqslant\frac{2x^2y^2}{x^2+y^2}\leqslant2\frac{(x^2+y^2)^2}{x^2+y^2}=2(x^2+y^2).\tag1$$So, by the squeeze theorem,$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{2x^2y^2}{x^2+y^2}=0.$$

Or, given $\varepsilon>0$, you can take $\delta=\sqrt{\frac\varepsilon2}$. If $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta$, then, by $(1)$,$$\frac{2x^2y^2}{x^2+y^2}<2\sqrt{\frac\varepsilon2}^2=\varepsilon.$$

Answer (score 4):

Use polar coordinates: let $r$ be the polar radius ($r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$), $\theta$ the polar angle. If $(x,y)\ne (0,0)$,
$$f(x,y)=\frac{2x^2y^2}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{2r^4\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta}{r^2}
=\tfrac12r^2\sin^22\theta.$$
Can you take it from there?